# How to change the color of a QSlider's handle according to its position

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qslider

[image]

I'd like the handle of the slider to go from blue to yellow. When set on the left, it's blue; and when you move it to the right, it will have a gradient from blue to yellow.

If it is possible through style sheets, how? And if not, how can I implement that in the paintEvent of a subclass of QSlider?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually you don't really have to do anything fancy, the stock `QSlider` already has the `valueChanged(int)` signal, so you can connect that to a function which mixes between the two colors based on the position and sets the style color. Here is a minimal example:

```
static QColor operator+(const QColor & a, const QColor & b) {
  return QColor(a.red() + b.red(), a.green() + b.green(), a.blue() + b.blue());
}
static QColor operator*(const QColor & c, const qreal r) {
  return QColor(c.red() * r, c.green() * r, c.blue() * r);
}

class Widget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent), from(248, 181, 20), to(64, 150, 214) {
      auto l = new QHBoxLayout(this);
      setLayout(l);
      s = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, this);
      s->setMinimum(0);
      s->setMaximum(100);
      l->addWidget(s);
      connect(s, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, &Widget::colorize);
      colorize(s->value());
    }
  private:
    void colorize(int v) {
      int d = s->maximum() - s->minimum();
      v = v - s->minimum();
      qreal rv = qreal(v) / d;
      QColor c = from * rv + to * (1.0 - rv);
      s->setStyleSheet(QString("QSlider::handle:horizontal {background-color: %1;}").arg(c.name()));
    }
    QSlider * s;
    QColor from, to;
};
```

This will work for any slider range and orientation, the code basically finds the relative handle position in range 0.0 to 1.0 and uses that to mix the `from` and `to` colors to set the handle color to the respective value. Oddly enough, `QColor` didn't have the operators to multiply and add, which can come quite in handy.

[image]

Additionally, instead of mixing between two colors you can construct a color in HSL format, which will give you a slightly different gradient. Changing `from/to` from `QColor` to hues 42 and 202 respectively, you can then:

```
QColor c = QColor::fromHsl(205 - (205 - 42) * rv, 200, 135);
```

This will give you a color sweep for the hue rather than mix between two fixed colors, which may be more applicable in the context of temperature:

[image]

Note that now in the middle you get a cyan-ish color rather than "zombie" green and you get through clean green before you get to orange.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe you can do this using a simple style sheet. But that's easily doable by specializing `QSlider` class and applying an appropriate stylesheet when user moves the cursor (i.e: when [valueChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) is emited).

Here is a class I wrote that does the trick. It works for horizontal and vertical cursor and can be customized to use any color. It create a [QImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) from a [QLinearGradient](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineargradient.html) to store the gradient color map, then, when slider value changes, it extracts the appropriate color from the image based on slider's position and applies it through a stylesheet.

Tried to make the class generic for reusability, but it could be simplified if you don't need to customize colors and only use horizontal sliders.

**gradientslider.h:**

```
#include <QSlider>
#include <QImage>
#include <QColor>

class GradientSlider : public QSlider
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GradientSlider( QColor from, QColor to, Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget* parent );

private slots:
    void changeColor( int );

private:
    QImage gradient;
};
```

**gradientslider.cpp:**

```
#include "gradientslider.h"
#include <QLinearGradient>
#include <QPainter>

GradientSlider::GradientSlider( QColor from, QColor to, Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget* parent ) :
    QSlider( orientation, parent ),
    gradient( QSize(100,100), QImage::Format_RGB32 )
{
    // create linear gradient
    QLinearGradient linearGrad( QPointF(0, 0), (orientation==Qt::Horizontal) ? QPointF(100, 0) : QPointF(0, 100) );
    linearGrad.setColorAt(0, from);
    linearGrad.setColorAt(1, to);

    // paint gradient in a QImage:
    QPainter p(&gradient);
    p.fillRect(gradient.rect(), linearGrad);

    connect( this, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(changeColor(int)) );

    // initialize
    changeColor( value() );
}

void GradientSlider::changeColor( int pos )
{
    QColor color;

    if ( orientation() == Qt::Horizontal )
    {
        // retrieve color index based on cursor position
        int posIndex = gradient.size().width() * ( pos - minimum() ) / (maximum() - minimum());
        posIndex = std::min( posIndex, gradient.width() - 1 );

        // pickup appropriate color
        color = gradient.pixel( posIndex, gradient.size().height()/2 );
    }
    else
    {
        // retrieve color index based on cursor position
        int posIndex = gradient.size().height() * ( pos - minimum() ) / (maximum() - minimum());
        posIndex = std::min( posIndex, gradient.height() - 1 );

        // pickup appropriate color
        color = gradient.pixel( gradient.size().width()/2, posIndex );
    }

    // create and apply stylesheet!
    // can be customized to change background and handle border!
    setStyleSheet( "QSlider::handle:" + (( orientation() == Qt::Horizontal ) ? QString("horizontal"):QString("vertical")) + "{ \
                               border-radius: 5px; \
                               border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; \
                               width: 20px; \
                               margin: -5px 0;   \
                               background: " + color.name() + "}" );
}
```

Now just do:

```
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout( this );
// horizontal slider:
layout->addWidget( new GradientSlider( QColor(79,174,231), QColor(251,192,22), Qt::Horizontal, this ) );
// or, vertical slider:
layout->addWidget( new GradientSlider( QColor(79,174,231), QColor(251,192,22), Qt::Vertical, this ) );
```

Colors `QColor(79,174,231)` (~blue) and `QColor(251,192,22)` (~yellow) were picked up from the image in the original question post and can be replaced by `Qt::blue`, `Qt::yellow` (ending up with slightly different coloration).

This will do it:

[image]
[image]
[image]